# from_array() method in Datamapper ORM Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-datamapper

I'm using DATAMAPPER ORM V1.8.2. I have a question for **from_array** method:

Firstly, I have a dropdown with *name="group_id"*

```
<select name="group_id" class="small-input">
      <option value="1">Guest</option>
      <option value="2" selected="selected">Member</option>
      <option value="3">Manager</option>
       <option value="4">Administrator</option>
</select>
```

In table users (database), I have a field named: **group_id**.

In controller:

```
....
$user->from_array($_POST, array('username', 'email', 'status', 'group_id'));
....
// then save
....
```

All things is OK.

But when I pass third parameter of **from_array()** is **TRUE** to save immediately, like:

```
$user->from_array($_POST, array('username', 'email', 'status', 'group_id', TRUE));
```

**It can't get group_id from $_POST.**
Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Do you have any validation on the user object? If so, check the `$user->error->all` for maybe the validation stops the save.

Comment: I received 1 message: The Group relationship is required, while the group input has completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename the `group_id` form field to the relation name in either `$has_one` (so probably `group`) or in the `$has_many` (probably `groups`) and add that name to the `$fields` array when calling the `from_array()`. So something like this:

```
// $_POST = array('group' => 3); // let's say this is what's coming in    
$user->from_array($_POST, array('username', 'email', 'status', 'group', TRUE));
```

Notice the symmetry:

- the relation called *group*
- the input parameter called *group*
- the field called *group*

---

This is what's happening:

1. You have a `required` on your `User` model's `group` field, which is the relation's name.
2. You try to update and save a `User` instance and with an input field named `group_id`, however the relation is named **group**.
3. Inside the array extension's `from_array()` method the code [checks every key is its a `has_one` or a `has_many` relation](https://github.com/WanWizard/sparks-datamapper/blob/1.8.2.1/extensions/array.php#L150) to gather the related objects for the final save. Since your data have `group_id` but your relation is named `group` they **don't match**, the related group instance is not fetched.
4. At the end of the `from_array()` [save is called with the related objects gathered](https://github.com/WanWizard/sparks-datamapper/blob/1.8.2.1/extensions/array.php#L209) while looping trough the fields, in your case with no objects.
5. The validation kicks in, and [tries to `_count_related()`](https://github.com/WanWizard/sparks-datamapper/blob/1.8.2.1/libraries/datamapper.php#L5543) for your user's groups but it won't find the group and the ["and take these with you too" second array](https://github.com/WanWizard/sparks-datamapper/blob/1.8.2.1/libraries/datamapper.php#L5268) is empty (this is where the objects gathered in step 3. would appear)
6. The `related_required` validation fails and stops the save process.

Comment: Thank you very much. I rename group_id field to group, all things is OK. Summary, if group is the relation, I will add group to the $fields insted of group_id?

Comment: I'm not sure that i understand your question, but i think yes. You have to use the same field name in the input (in your case `$_POST`) and the field list for `from_array()` as the validation rule and the relation. No group_id should be needed this way.